# Simples Dockerfile to read data from text file and output

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to create a very simple Dockerfile with the following content

```
FROM scratch
COPY helloworld.txt helloworld.txt
CMD ["helloworld.txt"]
```

Here I want to read the content of text file and output it but not able to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might utilize `cat` function that takes a file name as a argument.

```
tomasz@fox:~$ cat some.txt
foo
```

So in your Dockerfile it'd look like:

```
FROM alpine
COPY helloworld.txt helloworld.txt
CMD cat helloworld.txt
```

**EDIT**

like stated in a comment by Mark, `scratch` is a empty image. I didn't spot that. Basically you might use a predefined image like `ubuntu` or `alpine`. Alpine is very lightweight and contains `cat`.

Comment: You don't have `cat` in scratch, scratch is empty. You need to use either a Linux parent image in your Dockerfile and use `cat`, or if you want to use scratch, you need to write and compile a binary that can run standalone in an empty image and print the txt file with it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I get it now.
But as I am on Windows and within Command Prompt, can I use something like notepad helloworld.txt to open helloworld.txt file?